# Set time Range for a Day in datetime picker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

I am using Bootstrap datetime picker.
Is there any way to set time range like from 9.00 am to 6.00 pm for current and future date selections as well ?
so only time between 9.00 am to 6.00 pm  is enable rest will be disabled.

Comment: can u please provide a fiddle or sample code for the same?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/4297/

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('#pickerID')
    .datetimepicker({
        disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment()
            .hour(0), moment()
            .hour(9)
            .minutes(0)], [moment()
            .hour(18)
            .minutes(0), moment()
            .hour(24)]]
    });
```

Comment: It is working for the current date ,but if I want to disable it for future date as well?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working....

```
 

    $('.date').datetimepicker().on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('.date').datetimepicker('disabledTimeIntervals', [[moment(e.date)
                .hour(0).minute(0), moment(e.date)
                .hour(8)
                .minutes(59)], [moment(e.date)
                .hour(18)
                .minutes(30), moment(e.date)
                .hour(24)]]);
        });
```